How to convert long press gesture to coordinate in a SwiftUI Map view?
I am trying to get the coordinates for a long press gesture on a map. When I add the long press gesture the user can no longer move the map around. I tried using a simultaneous gesture and it did not work. This works however with a tap gesture for me as seen in this answer.
Tested on Xcode Sim and Real device running latest iOS and Xcode version, does not work.
I also don't mind using a single tap gesture to get the screen coordinates since that works (my use case is dropping a pin on the map). But the problem with the single tap gesture is that: double taps cause the map to zoom in while also triggering the single tap gesture. I don't want both to happen at the same time. Double taps should only zoom in the map and single taps should only get the screen coordinates. I have some code that attempts to filter out double taps but it doesn't work; 2 quick taps are recognized as 1 tap (tap gesture only recognizes the taps with enough time in between). I tried using the count argument and simultaneous gestures but nothing worked.
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        MapReader { reader in
            Map()
                .gesture (
                    LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 1.0)
                        .sequenced(before: DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0))
                        .onEnded { value in
                            switch value {
                            case .second(true, let drag):
                                if let location = drag?.location {
                                    let pinLocation = reader.convert(location, from: .local)
                                    if let pin = pinLocation {
                                        UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .rigid).impactOccurred()
                                        let lat = pin.latitude
                                        let long = pin.longitude
                                        
                                    }
                                }
                            default:
                                break
                            }
                        }
                )
        }
    }
}

          .onTapGesture(perform: { screenCoord in
                tapCount += 1      //tapCount initially zero
                if tapCount == 1 {
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                        if tapCount == 1 {
                             if let loc = mapProxy.convert(screenCoord, from: .local) { 
                                 //single tap recognized
                             }
                        }
                        tapCount = 0
                    }
                }
            })


Could not replicate your problem, all works well for me, the user can
move the map around and I can display the lat,long using print("-----> lat: \(lat)  long: \(long)").
I’m on, MacOS 15, Xcode 16, target iOS-18, tested on real ios device and MacCatalyst.

@workingdogsupportUkraine does this work for you on an iPhone? I tested it on a real device and it didn't work for me.

yes, works for me on real iPhone, (I had to change mapProxy to reader).

@workingdogsupportUkraine very odd Im running the newest version of Xcode on the latest iOS and it doesn't work for me on both the simulator and real device.

Although I could not replicate your issue with your original code, here is
a different approach to give you the option to interact with the map
or not according to your choice.
The key to this approach is to change the Map interaction mode.
Example code using a Picker and a LongPressGesture.
You could also use the same approach with, for example,
.gesture(SpatialTapGesture()....
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var modes = MapInteractionModes.all
    @State private var isMaping = false  // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Picker("", selection: $isMaping) {  // <-- here
            Text("Map move").tag(false)
            Text("Map static").tag(true)
        }.pickerStyle(.segmented)
        
        MapReader { reader in
            Map(interactionModes: modes)  // <-- here
                .gesture (
                    LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.5)
                        .sequenced(before: DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0))
                        .onEnded { value in
                            switch value {
                            case .second(true, let drag):
                                if let location = drag?.location {
                                    let pinLocation = reader.convert(location, from: .local)
                                    if let pin = pinLocation {
                                        UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .rigid).impactOccurred()
                                        let lat = pin.latitude
                                        let long = pin.longitude
                                        print("-----> lat: \(lat)  long: \(long)")
                                    }
                                }
                            default:
                                break
                            }
                        }
                )
        }
        .onChange(of: isMaping) {  // <-- here
            if isMaping {
                modes.subtract(.all)
            } else {
                modes.update(with: .all)
            }
        }
    }
}

Note, you may be interested in the test code I have on github
to draw an interactive polygon on a Map, MapPoly

Thanks, it's not very reasonable to have the user disable the map to drop a pin. This defintley works though so thanks. I'm just looking for a way to have a long press while the map is interactive.

It took me half day to get it work right.
It recognizes touch location on a map, and after LongPressureGesture it runs some action but before user stop pressing.
Here is the code:
.simultaneousGesture(
    DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
        .onChanged { value in
            let location = value.startLocation
            if let pinLocation = proxy.convert(location, from: .local) {
                longPressLocation = pinLocation
            }
        }
        .simultaneously(with: LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.5)
            .onEnded { _ in
                if let longPressLocation {
                    // do something before user stop pressing
                }
            }
        )
)

